# Dynamic css import with Jinja2

Tags: python, html, django, dynamic, jinja2

I am trying to make my stylesheets dynamic with django (jinja2) and I want to do something like this:

    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/{{ block css }}{{ endblock }}.css' %}">`

Apparently, I can't use Jinja in Jinja :), and I don't know how to make this work another way.

Comment: Why not include separate files based on conditions?

Comment: How exactly? Sorry, I am fairly new... Could you please precise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works out pretty well.

I use
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block css %}{% endblock %}">` in the template

 and then: `{% block css%}{% static 'home/css/file.css' %}{% endblock %` in each page

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
{% if condition == True %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='file1.css'>
{% else %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='file2.css'>
{% endif %}
```

And so on.

Comment: That would become very messy on a large scale actually ;(